# How to use input$id outside of reactive context in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I need to use a `Shiny` `input$id` outside the reactive context, inside an if statement. I can't use any reactivity inside this if, but I need to access the `input$id` value inside it. As expected, when I do this I get the following response:

> Can't access reactive value 'createshinyid' outside of reactive consumer.
> ℹ Do you need to wrap inside reactive() or observe()?

I know very well that in this case you must use the `input$id` inside a reactive function. This is not the issue here.

I need to use it outside the reactive context, inside an if statement because my application can refuse to start using it or accept it.

I cannot use `observe`, `observeEvent`, `reactive` or any other reactive function. I need to access the `input$id` outside of reactivities.

I will explain my code below:

I have this `JS` function:

```
$(document).on("shiny:sessioninitialized",function() {
  $.get("https://api.ipify.org", function(response)
    {Shiny.setInputValue("createshinyid", response);
  });
});
```

It creates `input$createshinyid`.

This function accesses the user's IP of an application.

I need to put it inside an if without reactivity on it.

See part of my code (the application is very large, so I adapted it):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tags$script(
  '$(document).on("shiny:sessioninitialized",function() {
    $.get("https://api.ipify.org", function(response)
      {Shiny.setInputValue("createshinyid", response);
      });
    });'
  ),
  
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "text1"), 
  
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "text2")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  df_1 <- data.frame(
    ip = c("123.456.789", "333.333.333"),
    n = c(1:2)
  )
    
    if ( ( ("333.333.333") %in% input$createshinyid ) == TRUE ) {
      
      output$texto1 <- renderPrint({
        
        print("ok")
        
      })
      
    } else ({
      
      output$texto2 <- renderPrint({
        
        print("Nok")
        
      })
      
    })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The server side contains a lot of Javascript. Using `reactive`, `observe`, or `observeEvent` or similar causes some interference in the code, for example, when I click once, it clicks twice...

So I need to use `input$createshinyid` outside the reactive context, inside this if statement.

Comment: Why not use it inside `output$texto1 <- renderPrint({...})`?

Comment: Because my application has 5000 lines on the server side, and has several renderers, such as renderValueBox, renderGauge, renderInfoBox, renderText, renderUI... I need to start the application with this if, but I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question, literrally is: *"this is not possible"*. But you can do that:

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  df_1 <- data.frame(
    ip = c("123.456.789", "333.333.333"),
    n = c(1:2)
  )
  
  condition <- reactive({
    "333.333.333" %in% input$createshinyid
  })
  
  output$text1 <- renderPrint({
    req(condition())
    print("ok")
  })
  
  
  output$text2 <- renderPrint({
    req(!condition())
    print("Nok")
  })
  
}
```